# Hiding Default Chart

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

I am new to magento platform. I have a quick question in regards to hiding a default setting. currently we are using version Magento ver. 1.9.0.1. We have setup a custom price break table. But it when you select a product attibute, a chart drops down and shows you savings if you buy more, how do i hide that?

Our store is multi-store using same backend for different structured pricing.

thepoultryhatchery.com/index.php/shipping
thepoultryhatchery.com/index.php/storpickup

store is in maintenance mode, so you have to use the index.php to access. but ive attached screen shot of what i want hidden for reference. Can you please provide me with proper steps to hide it from front end (to the customer)? on both stores?

[image]

Comment: Can you please remove the important word from the title? I tried to edit myself your question but the title was short without that word.

Comment: Changed it as per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on your theme, but somewhere in your themes files under app/design/frontend/THEMEBASE/THEME/calatog/product/view.phtml

you can find this:

```
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
```

This outputs your tier prices, so try and uncomment it, although you may have to uncomment or remove some javascript as well by the looks of your theme.

You may also look for

```
<div id="SCPcustomOptionsDiv" style="">
```

As this is the container of the tier prices in your theme.

Comment: Worked! Thank you :D